# How to translate-golf the introduction of "I Have a Dream" by Martin Luther King?

Tags: traducción, translation-golf, inglés

Let's continue with the Translation Golf game, this time with a quote from the famous [I Have a Dream](http://www.americanrhetoric.com/speeches/mlkihaveadream.htm) by Martin Luther King. Specifically, its introduction:

> I am happy to join with you today in what will go down in history as the greatest demonstration for freedom in the history of our nation.

It is a pompous introduction to an ingenious speech, which I would translate as follows (**121 characters**):

> Estoy contento de unirme hoy a vosotros en lo que pasará a la historia como la mayor manifestación por la libertad en la historia de nuestra nación.

Let's try to make translations that do not summarise, but effectively translate. So don't just propose *¡qué bien que estamos aquí arrejuntados!*, but a text including all that was said by the reverend. This way, we will focus on the pursuit of words and expressions to tweak the counter and let all of us learn more about the Spanish language.

[**Follow the rules**](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/1674) and explain your answers so we can validate them. You have 7 days to answer. Let's get the game started!

---

Final ranking:

1. **[Carlos Alejo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20491/1674) 70 characters**
2. [rsanchez](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20494/1674) 81
3. [Diego](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20490/1674) 92
4. [guifa](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20489/1674) 95
5. [aparente001](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20495/1674) 153

<s>I cannot help asking: isn't anybody going to use [*suma*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YglJQru) (*3. f. Lo más sustancial e importante de algo.*) to translate "the greatest"?</s> Status completed :)

Comment: Tus deseos son órdenes. :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## <strike>84 73</strike> 70 caracteres

> Soy feliz por nuestra reunión hoy, que los anales tendrán por suma señal pro libertad.

Explicaciones:

- Las personas se unen ("join") en reuniones ("conjunto de personas reunidas"), luego uso "nuestra reunión" en vez de "unirme a vosotros".
- Entiendo que la propia reunión (y lo que salga de ella) es lo que pasará a formar parte de la historia como la mayor manifestación de libertad, de ahí introducir la segunda parte con "que" y no con "en lo que".
- Coincido en que la palabra "historia" aparece dos veces, y por tanto una es redundante. Es posible que la primera se refiera a la historia en general, y la segunda a la historia específica del país. Se entiende que si algo entra en la historia de un país, entra en la historia también en general. Se usa además "nuestra historia" como "la historia de nuestro país" (es difícil entender esa expresión como otro tipo de historia de menor categoría).
- Según el diccionario, "[tener](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZT8sFSB)" significa "juzgar, reputar, considerar" (acepción 9), y pone como ejemplo "tener a alguien por rico". Luego "la historia tendrá por la mayor" equivale a "la historia considerará la mayor".
- Entiendo "manifestación" como la acción de "manifestar algo" (no de "manifestarse"), en el sentido de "declarar, dar a conocer", por lo que entiendo que una "manifestación de libertad" y una "expresión de libertad" son sinónimos. Además, el Merriam-Webster define "demonstration" como "an outward *expression* or display", luego más a mi favor para usar "expresión".

Mejoras:

- Cambio "estoy" por "soy". Es un recurso literario: "[Soy feliz de oírtelo decir.](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=1&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=130417%5C023%5CC000O13042017234809993.1180.1176&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20Soy%20feliz%20de%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCREA%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto1)"
- Cambio "expresión" por "señal", que según el diccionario es "imagen o representación de algo". En este caso de la libertad deseada. Se considera [sinónimo de "manifestación"](http://www.sinonimos.com/sinonimo.php?palabra=manifestaci%F3n&x=0&y=0) en el sentido de "exhibición, muestra".
- Cambio "nuestra historia tendrá" por "los anales tendrán". "[Anales](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2VOEwMd)" (siempre en plural) es sinónimo de "historia" según el DLE. La expresión "nuestros anales" no se suele recoger. En todo caso, "los anales" se puede referir tanto a la historia del país como en general, por la misma razón esgrimida antes.
- Por propuesta del OP, cambio "la mayor" por "suma", con el significado de "la más sustancial e importante".

---

Alternativa considerando la historia general y la particular del país (y sin las mejoras):

### 86 caracteres

> Estoy feliz por nuestra reunión hoy, que la historia tendrá por la mayor expresión pro libertad del país.

- Se entiende "del país" como "la mayor que se haya hecho en el país", luego equivale a "de la historia del país" (al haber usado ya la palabra "historia" previamente, se entiende). Se entiende igualmente que está hablando del propio país, el país en el que está teniendo lugar la reunión, y no de otro, por lo que se omite "nuestro".

Comment: ¡Gran aportación! Tengo una pequeña objeción: _expresión de libertad_ no me cuadra demasiado para decir _manifestación por la libertad_ ("demonstration for freedom"). El contexto en el que se mencionó este texto es una marcha por los derechos de los negros, ergo lo que Luther King quería destacar aquí es la unión de la gente _para_ conseguir libertad, no el hecho de que se reunieran _en_ libertad.

Comment: @fedorqui lo cambio por "pro" (en el DLE como "pro-" aunque se puede usar como palabra suelta).

Comment: ¡¡Muy bien resuelto!! Será muy difícil de batir.

Comment: @fedorqui no hables tan rápido... 

Comment: Ve preparando pregunta porque me da que vas a ganar :)

Comment: @fedorqui esperaba algún pique de última hora, pero veo que tras las propuestas iniciales la cosa esta vez ha estado un poco parada...

Comment: Lamento muchísimo el olvido, ayer me lié y se me pasó completamente "cerrar" esta pregunta. Aceptada. ¡Muchas gracias una vez más por estrujar la lengua!

Answer (score 5):

#### 95 letras

> Pláceme unirosme hoy para lo que la historia marcará como la mayor muestra pro libertad na historia del país de nós.

Comment: menudu furiatón estes fechu xD gústame ver asturianos per internet

Comment: @loia6b lo bono de les regles ye que si ta nel DLE, podemos usalo, asina coses como *na* y *nos* (de suxetu) puese usar. ;-)

Comment: @lois6b pero que conste, nun soi falante patrimonial

Comment: Dicho lo cual: guifa, has roto la banca :) ¿Puedes poner la referencia por la cual _nós_ es aceptada? En el DRAE no aparece.

Comment: Si no aparece, que no lo se, puedes cambiar por "del nuesu país" ?

Comment: @fedorqui estoy en el móvil (por eso no conté las letras) pero es la 3.ª acepción de *nos* en el DLE (lo que pasa es que, siendo tónico y no átono, la mayoría de los libros cuando lo emplean prefieren tildarlo, costumbre que sigo y que, según la Ortografía 2010 también se debe hacer (aunque no hace referencia a esta palabra, probablemente por ser tan poco usada)

Answer (score 5):

### 92 letras

> Me alegra uniros hoy en lo que la historia de nuestro país recordará como la mayor demostración por la libertad

111 caracteres contando espacios; 92 sin ellos.

Para esta traducción he considerado redundante el uso de "historia" que puede no serlo. La Historia y "la historia de nuestro país" pueden ser consideradas dos cosas distintas o un simple tecnicismo en la interpretación. La comunidad y el OP dirán si sí o si no...

---

He cambiado un poco mi versión inicial, ya que creo que no mantenía realmente el significado de "I'm Happy" simplemetne con "Feliz".

Comment: ¡La virgen del palodú, qué difícil lo habéis puesto nada más empezar! :-D

Comment: @CarlosAlejo, sí, pero como explico me tomo una licencia. Si aquellos que jugamos decidimos que no vale porque no coserva del todo el significado original, me caigo con todo el equipo a pesar de tener menos letras que otros...

Comment: Interesante punto es la traducción de _uniros_ para decir _join with you today_. No es literalmente lo mismo (en el original él se une a las masas, en la traducción se puede interpretar como que él el que ejerce de organizador de la [marcha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/March_on_Washington_for_Jobs_and_Freedom)), pero creo que es moderadamente aceptable. Problemente _unir**n**os_ sería más correcto.

Answer (score 5):

### 81 letras

> Me alegra unírmeles hoy en la marcha por la libertad que se recordará como la mayor de nuestro país.

Comment: Caramba, fantástica aproximación. Cuando parecía que no se podía acortar más...

Answer (score 3):

#### 153

> Me da mucho gusto unirme con ustedes el día de hoy en lo que la historia juzgará, sin duda, la manifestación por la libertad más importante  que se haya visto en la historia de nuestra nación.

Comment: I don't think this quote is appropriate for Translation Golf, because the game places importance on conciseness.  The rules state, "The translation with the least number of characters wins"; fortunately, so far at least, entries have not been judged solely on number of characters.  But in this case, the number of characters is particularly contradictory to the spirit of the original.

Martin Luther King, Jr., was a great orator.  We have to evaluate his oratory in his historical context.  His pompous style was intrinsic, essential to his effectiveness.  Pomposity does not go well with conciseness.

Just try reading the other entries in MLK oratory style.  Imagine yourself at the Lincoln Memorial, speaking to a quarter million people with a 1963 sound system.  You take your time!  You make music with your words!  You impress the crowd with your fancy expressions!

Other considerations in translating this text: the translation should be universally understood by all Spanish speakers the world over.  (I have no idea if my entry achieves that, but that was one of my goals, and should be for all entries, in my opinion.)

Also, this fragment doesn't seem to me to be one of the more challenging portions of the speech (in terms of translation to Spanish).

Great speech, though.

Comment: Maybe you're right, but I think a lot can be learnt and discovered even from what could seem the simplest sentences.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo - With plenty of other texts, that would be fine.  Sure!  An intellectual exercise!  With this one, though, speaking frankly, it feels offensive.

Comment: I am quite concerned in making this game better for all, so allow me to ask you how would you make it better. Would you like longer sentences, or more challenging sentences?

Comment: @CarlosAlejo - Thanks for asking.  However, in this case I cannot select a challenging section of the speech because I don't see this speech as being appropriate for the game.  Now, Malcolm X, another great orator of the same country and historical period, but a completely different style, would be a good choice for a *concise* translation.  In my opinion.  How about the chickens coming home to roost quote?  Or the quote about the house Negroes and the field Negroes?

Comment: @aparente001 while you have a point, this is just a game. On a regular question you would never consider number of characteres to be something to judge the quality of an answer upon. But I understand your point about the game. I made a comment myself about my proposal. I took the risk to take out what I considered was redundat to save characters. Others could have argued that by doing that I wasn't really keeping the meaning, so I would not have had a best answer even if I had the least characters. Since it's a game, no hard feelings. The discussion can be as entertaining as the game itself

Comment: Thanks for answering the insight on the selection of the text. In the previous edition of the game we noticed that answers (mine for example) were summarizing the text together with translating it. To prevent it I chose something that is giving a single, powerful, idea, to make the game focus on looking for synonyms and interesting tweaks. We all agree that the power of the speech is both in what was said and how it was said, and I would not feel that much touched if it was concise as the translations are. However, we wouldn't be listening to it in Spanish in Washington that day, either :D

Comment: Feel free to suggest improvements in the Meta question, or even better: try to squeeze this one so you win the game this time and you can chose the next text! By the way, [the rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/1674) do not allow abbreviations, so _Uds._ should be replaced by an unabbreviated synonym.